# Issue building URLs in swift using relativeToURL initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an iPhone app that interacts with an api. I was building a class that looked something like this:

```
class Api {
  let base_url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/")
  func users(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "users", relativeToURL: base_url)
    ...
  }
}
```

My intent is to have a base URL for the API and then the URLs for all the endpoints in the API are built using that base URL. However, I am finding that even tho I am able to successfully build URLs like I show above in a Playground project (so in the example above url represents `"http://localhost:3000/api/v1"`), when I try to do this in my app It does not work, it builds a weird url (something like `"users --ttp://localhost:3000/api/v1/"`.
I'm a bit puzzled because it works on the playground project, but if I do the same on my app it doesn't.

Would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It built the right URL, it just displays weird. You can use `absoluteURL()` (or `absoluteString()`) to get a version of the URL that prints nicely.

---

Even though the `description()` returns a weird string, the correct URL would be used in `NSURLRequest` or any other object which takes a `NSURL`.

Comment: Curious as to why the description prints out that weird string. As I mention above, they are able to print out the correct string in a playground. Thanks!